# get count from using multiple tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In my Sql have...4 tables like..

```
classtable
sid     date    timetableid
ct1      -       tt1
ct2      -       tt2
ct3     --       tt3
```

and my `Timetable`

```
sid    startDate   skillsetid
tt1      ---        ss1
tt2      ---        ss1
tt3      ---        ss2
```

and my `Skillset`

```
sid     courseid
ss1        c1
ss2        c2
```

and finally my `Course` table.

```
sid    name
c1     java
c2     flex
```

Finally my requirement is count the no.of courses.. using `Classtable`

for example according to above tables  `2-java` and `1-flex` so these count will be displayed on my html page like 2(java)  or 4(flex)..etc .. what ever we get the count...
so please suggest me how to get count and display on html..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your tables and group the result:

```sql
SELECT   Course.name, COUNT(*)
FROM     classtable
    JOIN Timetable ON Timetable.sid = classtable.timetableid
    JOIN Skillset  ON  Skillset.sid = Timetable.skillsetid
    JOIN Course    ON    Course.sid = Skillset.courseid
GROUP BY Course.sid
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4298a/1/0).